# why doesn't this imaplib request work all the time?

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I'm using imaplib and attempting to parse messages from a gmail acct.  My code has worked for months, and now all of the sudden it's failing miserably.  I have no idea what to attribute this to.

The following works around 1/3 of the time.  By 'works', I mean succeeds in printing something other than 'no new messages' when I receive an email.  Would anyone have any suggestions of more robust ways to attempt this?  Or maybe suggestions of now to configure gmail accounts to get this to work more reliably?

I'm also generally interested if the way I've coded this seems like good practice.
Thanks for any and all help...

```
def check_email(interval):
    while True:
        server.select('INBOX')
        status, ids = server.search(None, 'UnSeen')

        if not ids or ids[0] is '': 
            print 'no new messages'
        else:
            print 'found a message; attempting to parse...'
            latest_id = ids[0]
            status, msg_data = server.fetch(latest_id, '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
            raw_data = msg_data[0][1]
            char_array = list(raw_data)
            print 'message result: ', char_array 

        time.sleep(interval)
```

EDIT1: I am now getting the following error:

> "imaplib.error: FETCH command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']"

Does anyone know what I can attribute this to?  It's apparently a result of the line

```
status, msg_data = server.fetch(latest_id, '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
```

EDIT2: I found out that I can log into the gmail account, click on the 'more' tab, then click on 'mark all as read' and all of the sudden the code works as expected.  Is there a way to mark all messages as read remotely with imaplib??

Comment: maybe should be accessing another IMAP email inbox aside from gmail?  i don't know if that is where the problem is...  :/

Comment: Do you have another program/service that is checking your mailbox? It could be marking messages as seen.

Comment: I've come back to the same problem here...  modifying my original question.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: No, I'm not using another service...